# HTTP Post request read the response

Tags: java, rest, http-post

I send a post to a mail api like this:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)MAIL_SERVER_URL.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(toSend.build().toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
os.flush();
os.close();


System.out.println(String.format("Failed : HTTP error code[%s] msa[%s]",conn.getResponseCode(), conn.getResponseMessage()));  


InputStreamReader rd = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(rd);

String output;
System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
   while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
}

conn.disconnect();
```

The api give me a response like this:
[image]

I don't know how read, using Java, the message in the body of the response.
This line `new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());` always generate ad exception like this:

```
Severe:   java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8182/mailapi/highpriority
```

Comment: Use a better http client.

Comment: Why don't you use some framework like Jackson or similar to serialize and deserialize your JSON objects? https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, in this case I need to process only simple JSON objects. In future projects probably I will use these libraries